# Delete values on one column based on other

Tags: r

I am trying to delete values from one column, becauste at the beginning it was easy for me to calculate even though I knew them useless

I will paste a database example

```
sample <- structure(list(id = structure(c(60901027, 50203031, 50203031, 
50203012, 60901031, 130105045, 110606056, 60901028, 140103036, 
140102092, 140103027, 120715019, 120715030, 70802012, 110104030, 
120715012, 50203010, 111202007, 60901038, 111202007, 50109027, 
70713001, 110104030, 50202099, 70802015, 70802013, 140103028, 
120715033, 120715035, 60901020), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    gen = c("lrp1", "cav1", "pcsk9", "lag3", "il1b", "olr1", 
    "s1pr3", "abca1", "pcsk9", "18s", "pcsk9", "ldlr", "nfe2l2", 
    "nfe2l2", "cxcl2", "pik3cb", "18s", "ptgs1", "il23a", "olr1", 
    "lag3", "nfe2l2", "ldlr", "nlrp3", "cxcl2", "ifng", "s1pr3", 
    "abcg4", "nr1h3", "cav1"), time = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3"), endogenous_ct_01 = structure(c(12.5023333333333, 12.6883333333333, 
    12.6883333333333, 11.8116666666667, 13.0026666666667, 12.252, 
    NA, 12.4206666666667, NA, 12.0706666666667, 11.282, 11.3463333333333, 
    12.2743333333333, 11.3893333333333, 12.4383333333333, 11.114, 
    11.4886666666667, NA, NA, NA, 12.6483333333333, 11.9643333333333, 
    12.4383333333333, 12.031, 12.0893333333333, 12.2883333333333, 
    NA, 11.4923333333333, 11.2346666666667, 12.476), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "F12.9", display_width = 12L), 
    endogenous_ct_03 = structure(c(12.4386666666667, 12.4023333333333, 
    12.4023333333333, 11.46, 12.8173333333333, 11.0113333333333, 
    12.0926666666667, 11.4846666666667, 12.6406666666667, 11.8363333333333, 
    11.9383333333333, 11.8566666666667, 11.9683333333333, 12.2423333333333, 
    11.6673333333333, 11.6866666666667, 13.669, 12.435, 12.0433333333333, 
    12.435, 12.893, 13.863, 11.6673333333333, 12.164, 13.1386666666667, 
    12.715, 10.6446666666667, 12.3526666666667, 11.347, 12.424
    ), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "F11.8", display_width = 11L), 
    value = c(18.303, 23.836, NA, 20.203, 17.434, 24.27, 20.118, 
    17.118, 27.757, 10.271, NA, 17.701, 16.772, 16.329, 24.491, 
    16.839, 11.764, 16.797, 22.637, 21.85, 22.634, 18.252, 16.937, 
    15.684, 23.962, 23.765, 18.873, NA, 19.989, 23.829)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The df

```
     id    gen time endogenous_ct_01 endogenous_ct_03  value
1   60901027   lrp1    3         12.50233         12.43867 18.303
2   50203031   cav1    3         12.68833         12.40233 23.836
3   50203031  pcsk9    3         12.68833         12.40233     NA
4   50203012   lag3    3         11.81167         11.46000 20.203
5   60901031   il1b    3         13.00267         12.81733 17.434
6  130105045   olr1    1         12.25200         11.01133 24.270
7  110606056  s1pr3    3               NA         12.09267 20.118
8   60901028  abca1    3         12.42067         11.48467 17.118
9  140103036  pcsk9    3               NA         12.64067 27.757
10 140102092    18s    3         12.07067         11.83633 10.271
11 140103027  pcsk9    3         11.28200         11.93833     NA
12 120715019   ldlr    3         11.34633         11.85667 17.701
13 120715030 nfe2l2    3         12.27433         11.96833 16.772
14  70802012 nfe2l2    1         11.38933         12.24233 16.329
15 110104030  cxcl2    1         12.43833         11.66733 24.491
16 120715012 pik3cb    3         11.11400         11.68667 16.839
17  50203010    18s    3         11.48867         13.66900 11.764
18 111202007  ptgs1    3               NA         12.43500 16.797
19  60901038  il23a    3               NA         12.04333 22.637
20 111202007   olr1    3               NA         12.43500 21.850
21  50109027   lag3    3         12.64833         12.89300 22.634
22  70713001 nfe2l2    3         11.96433         13.86300 18.252
23 110104030   ldlr    3         12.43833         11.66733 16.937
24  50202099  nlrp3    3         12.03100         12.16400 15.684
25  70802015  cxcl2    1         12.08933         13.13867 23.962
26  70802013   ifng    3         12.28833         12.71500 23.765
27 140103028  s1pr3    3               NA         10.64467 18.873
28 120715033  abcg4    3         11.49233         12.35267     NA
29 120715035  nr1h3    3         11.23467         11.34700 19.989
30  60901020   cav1    3         12.47600         12.42400 23.829
```

I am trying to delete the values of endogenous_ct_01 when column time == 3, and endogenous_ct_03 when column time == 1. These values should not existe but I don't know an elegant way to do it (both dplyr and base syntax are welcome)

Comment: Try `sample[sample$time == 3, "endogenous_ct_01" ] <- NA` then `sample[sample$time == 1, "endogenous_ct_03" ] <- NA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% 
 mutate(endogenous_ct_01 = ifelse(time == 3, NA, endogenous_ct_01),
 endogenous_ct_03 = ifelse(time == 1, NA, endogenous_ct_03)) -> sample


#           id    gen time endogenous_ct_01 endogenous_ct_03  value
# 1   60901027   lrp1    3               NA         12.43867 18.303
# 2   50203031   cav1    3               NA         12.40233 23.836
# 3   50203031  pcsk9    3               NA         12.40233     NA
# 4   50203012   lag3    3               NA         11.46000 20.203
# 5   60901031   il1b    3               NA         12.81733 17.434
# 6  130105045   olr1    1         12.25200               NA 24.270
# 7  110606056  s1pr3    3               NA         12.09267 20.118
# 8   60901028  abca1    3               NA         11.48467 17.118
# 9  140103036  pcsk9    3               NA         12.64067 27.757
# 10 140102092    18s    3               NA         11.83633 10.271
# 11 140103027  pcsk9    3               NA         11.93833     NA
# 12 120715019   ldlr    3               NA         11.85667 17.701
# 13 120715030 nfe2l2    3               NA         11.96833 16.772
# 14  70802012 nfe2l2    1         11.38933               NA 16.329
# 15 110104030  cxcl2    1         12.43833               NA 24.491
# 16 120715012 pik3cb    3               NA         11.68667 16.839
# 17  50203010    18s    3               NA         13.66900 11.764
# 18 111202007  ptgs1    3               NA         12.43500 16.797
# 19  60901038  il23a    3               NA         12.04333 22.637
# 20 111202007   olr1    3               NA         12.43500 21.850
# 21  50109027   lag3    3               NA         12.89300 22.634
# 22  70713001 nfe2l2    3               NA         13.86300 18.252
# 23 110104030   ldlr    3               NA         11.66733 16.937
# 24  50202099  nlrp3    3               NA         12.16400 15.684
# 25  70802015  cxcl2    1         12.08933               NA 23.962
# 26  70802013   ifng    3               NA         12.71500 23.765
# 27 140103028  s1pr3    3               NA         10.64467 18.873
# 28 120715033  abcg4    3               NA         12.35267     NA
# 29 120715035  nr1h3    3               NA         11.34700 19.989
# 30  60901020   cav1    3               NA         12.42400 23.829
```